# Specific applications of the various modes of optical microscopy

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, material-science, microscopy

My question is primarily about reflected and transmitted light microscopy, and the BF and DF modes in both. I am aware of the basic working principles, to state it down briefly:

Transmitted light microscopy focuses the light through a condenser from below onto the sample, and the objective collects the light transmitted through the sample. If the entire light is collected, we have the BF image, where the contrast is created by attenuation of the light by the sample. If the direct beam that passes from the condenser through the sample is blocked off, and only the light scattered from the sample is collected, we have the DF image, where contrast is created by scattering from the sample. Reflected light microscopy is used for samples that do not transmit light, we use similar principles but with light reflected from the sample.

While characterizing samples, what mode is used for what specific application? For instance, if I want to see surface features, which mode is better?

Comment: I don't see how either BF (bright field) or DF (dark field) would be good for surface features...

Comment: @Pieter why do you say that? I remember one of my trainers saying that DF is better to look at surface features, but I do not know why that is the case.

Comment: If I do an image search for Dark Field microscopy, I do not see any surface photos. But your trainers would know more than me, so ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Dark field gives better contrast vs the background (no background light), bright field gives better resolution (better numerical aperture, lower depth of field).
For surface feature, oblique illumination is better because it casts shades.